# How to load es6 module into amd architecture

Tags: reactjs, requirejs, amd, jsx, babeljs

I have a requirejs app and I want to append a react module / component into my page. The react module is written in babel / jsx. So I use the AMD transform plugin AND I concat them into one single file.

Now of course each react js file has `export default class / function`-part.
One of the react files has a function called `startUp(html)` which expects a html-element as parameter. This html parameter will be used by `ReactDOM.render` call.

My problem is that I cannot access the startUp-method in my AMD-module:

```
////////////////////// REACT AND BABEL / ES6 CODE /////////////////////////
// react-module.js
export default class MyReactContainer extends React.Component {
    render() {
        return <div>Just a DIV</div>
    }
}

// react-main.js
export default function startUp(html) {
  ReactDOM.render(<MyReactContainer />, html);
}

//////////////////// EXISTING AMD MODULE /////////////////////////////////
// reactModuleIncluder.js
define(['./react-main'], function(reactMain) {

  function includeReactModule(html) {
      reactMain(html); // Here I want to call the startUp method
  }

  return includeReactModule;
});
```

Any idea what I can do? Or is this even possible?

EDIT: Solved the problem. Files were transpiled and concatenated in one single js file. Now I removed the concat-process and it works.

Comment: Is the React code transpiled with Babel first? At first look, it seems like you are mixing ES6 syntax into an ES5 project.

Comment: Purely from the pov of mixing ES6 and ES5 code and RequireJS, there's no reason you should not be able to do it. If you tell Babel to produce AMD modules, your ES6 code won't behave differently from modules written in ES5 from the get go. Can't say anything about React since I don't use it.

Answer (score -1):

Solved the problem. Files were transpiled and concatenated in one single js file. Now I removed the concat-process and it works.